# Why does BlockingCollection<T> not implement ICollection<T>?

Tags: .net, concurrent-collections

The current implementation looks like this:

```
public class BlockingCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>, ICollection, IEnumerable, IDisposable
```

Does anyone have an idea why it does not implement `ICollection<T>` as well? It's kind of anoying...

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) it also implements `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` (.net 4.5+).

Comment: The class isn't sealed, so if you really need it to implement that you could inherit and proxy the implementation manually.

Comment: @UweKeim Sure, but i want to add some items to the collection too...

Comment: Do keep in mind that `ICollection<T>` is very different from `ICollection`.  The Contains() method is the deal-breaker imo, essential to ICollection<> but can't implement it in an efficient thread-safe way.

Comment: Check out a very close question "Why doesn't ConcurrentBag<T> implement ICollection<T>?" https://stackoverflow.com/q/5611781/2680660

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one it does not implement [ICollection.Contains Method (T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5cf1d56.aspx)
As commented by Hans Contains() method cannot be implemented in an efficient thread-safe way.

Comment: @HansPassant I agree.  You want me to steal your Contains or just delete?